# How t resolve the error?Note: ThreadOp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program in java about threads.

```
class ThreadOp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("program started...");
        int x=36+54;
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){};
        System.out.println("sum is: "+x);
        //Thread...
        Thread t=Thread.currentThread();
        String tname=t.getName();
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        System.out.println("Current running thread is:"+tname);
        t.setName("MyMain");
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        System.out.println(t.getId());
        
        System.out.println("program ended...");
    }
}
```

However I am getting an error:
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Threads>javac ThreadOp.java
Note: ThreadOp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

What can I do to resolve it?

I am trying to understand how the various methods of threads work.
I am trying to implement the methods.

Comment: It is not an error, it is simply a warning the API in use in the compiler is out of date. Thread has many deprecated (no longer used) methods. If you recompile as it instructed it will tell you which methods should be replaced.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: How did you compile it in the first place?

Comment: The deprecation message says how to do it: by adding `-Xlint:deprecation` to the compiler flags.